# Vim: When using Vundle how can I also include a plugin that I am writing?

Tags: vim

Where should I put my own code when developing a plugin while at the same time using Vundle? I tried to use a local repo but I have to commit in order for vim to see the changes I am making… What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once Vundle has retrieved the plugin's source, you can just remove the directory of your bundle in the vim plugins directory and make a symbolic link to your git workspace.

```
rm -rf ~/.vim/bundle/yourplugin/
ln -s /path/to/the/plugin/youre/developing/plugin ~/.vim/bundle/yourplugin
```

It's more hackish than @demure's answer, but it works.

Comment: Just to clarify that the answer to my question is to symlink to the actual `.vim` directories (`.vim/plugin`, `.vim/doc`, `.vim/ftplugin` etc.). If you symlink directly inside the bundle uncommitted changes will not have effect.

Comment: No, if you do as the answer says, **Once Vundle has retrieved the plugin's source** you do not have to symlink to the specific plugins dirs, you can just symlink the whole thing into bundle. Vundle can sync plugins you're working on, but first you have to sync them via git, remove that directory it creates **and then** replace that directory with a symlink.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues/9), use the following:

```
Bundle '~/path/your-plugin/.git'
```

Where `~/path/your-plugin` is the working copy.

Comment: or you can just remove the directory of your bundle in the vim plugins directory and make a symbolic link to your git workspace. It's more hackish than this answer, but it works.

Comment: @demune Thanks for your answer but this doesn't do it. The plugin works but if I make a change vim doesn't load it. I have to make a commit and then call `BundleUpdate` which of course it is not possible when trying to write a plugin...

Comment: @zmo I tried to symlink my files to the .vim/plugin directory before  but it wouldn't work. I will give that another try.

Comment: @zmo Actually I tried again and the symlink solution works fine!! I must have been doing something wrong before. I you want submit your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!